# Simulate programmatically Start Menu press on windows mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile

Does anybody knows how to simulate programmatically Start Menu press on windows mobile 6.5?

Until now,
I successed to simulate programmatically pressing on F4 key, which brings the desktop window, using keybd_event API.
But,I preffer to simulate pressing on start menu (the button in the left buttom).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate a start meu click use kebd_event with VK_LWIN

Comment: Thanks, i used 
keybd_event(0x5B, 0, 0x0004, 0)